# Bug in Delphi 2009? -> *.res not found in project search path (works in Delphi 2006)

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I have a problem migrating from Delphi 2006 to Delphi 2009. A Project which uses the JVCL complains that jvconsts.res is missing. The file is definitly there. The project search path includes the directory where the file is located. (Note: I don't have JVCL in my global search path to make it more portable)

But the file should be found, as the [Delphi Help](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/compdirsresourcefile_xml.html) says:

> "... the linker searches for .res
>   files [...] in the directories
>   specified in the Search path input box
>   on the Directories/Conditionals page
>   of the Project|Options dialog box"

This is not a JVCL problem: A minimalistic program shows this:

Imagine this directory structure:

```
C:\Test\ResTest.dpr
C:\Test\Res\Test.res
```

Here is ResTest.dpr:

```
program ResTest;

{$R test.res} // not found even if "c:\Test\Res" is in project search path

begin
end.
```

This compiles fine in Delphi 2006 but not in Delphi 2009. 
After some searching I found, a way to tell Delphi where the file is: The gobal search path or the -R parameter using the command line compiler.

As I write this, I come closer to the real problem: In Delphi 2006 the .cfg-File includes the lines:

```
-I"c:\Test\Res"
-U"c:\Test\Res"
-R"c:\Test\Res"
```

Basicly it copies the values from the project search path into the 3 command line options and so it makes sure that the -R parameter has the right values.

In Delphi 2009 (I set the verbosity of the compiler output to "debug") I get the resulting command line from the IDE:

If the directory (c:\Test\Res) is included in the project search path:

```
dcc32.exe --no-config -M -Q -ID:\Sources\Temp\1\Res;"c:\program files\codegear\rad studio\6.0\Lib" -LE"C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\6.0\Bpl" -LN"C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\6.0\Dcp" -O"c:\program files\codegear\rad studio\6.0\Lib" -R"c:\program files\codegear\rad studio\6.0\Lib" -UD:\Sources\Temp\1\Res;"c:\program files\codegear\rad studio\6.0\Lib" -K00400000   ResTest.dpr
```

If the directory is included in the global search path

```
dcc32.exe --no-config -M -Q -ID:\Sources\Temp\1\Res;"c:\program files\codegear\rad studio\6.0\Lib";D:\Sources\Temp\1\Res -LE"C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\6.0\Bpl" -LN"C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\6.0\Dcp" -O"c:\program files\codegear\rad studio\6.0\Lib";D:\Sources\Temp\1\Res -R"c:\program files\codegear\rad studio\6.0\Lib";D:\Sources\Temp\1\Res -UD:\Sources\Temp\1\Res;"c:\program files\codegear\rad studio\6.0\Lib";D:\Sources\Temp\1\Res -K00400000   ResTest.dpr
```

Maybe its hard to see here: The difference is the -R parameter:

```
Local Search Path -> -R"c:\program files\codegear\rad studio\6.0\Lib"
Global Search Path -> -R"c:\program files\codegear\rad studio\6.0\Lib";D:\Sources\Temp\1\Res
```

So it's no wonder why it doesn't work. The local search path is not appended to the -R Parameter in Delphi 2009.

I would say, this is clearly a bug, but why seems that nobody else has this problem? I can reproduce it on all machines we use. Maybe the error only exists in the German version of Delphi 2009?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround is to put this in your code in stead:

```
{$R res\test.res}
```

That works on my system with Delphi 2009, both with the IDE and the command-line compiler.

Note that I agree that they broke existing functionality, did you add a report to Quality Portal? If not, please do: ttps://quality.embarcadero.com (this used to be the search engine indexed http://qc.embarcadero.com but that has been shut down; https://quality.embarcadero.com requires a free account to search).

Comment: This would work with our code, but I have to modify thirdparty code (JVCL) which I really like to avoid.

Comment: I created an entry in QualityCentral for this bug #73249

Comment: I agree with the fact that you do not want to modify 3rd party code.

Thx for the report.
I just checked http://qc.codegear.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=73249,  amended some of the report fields, then promoted it so the Q&A team at CodeGear will see it in their internal system

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).